# I'd like to leave only 10 letters behind

Tags: notepad++

For example I have:

```
Find more information about how to ask a good question here
```

I'd like to leave only 10 letters behind.

```
stion here
```

Comment: @Tetsujin Why? It seems clear enough to me and has been answered.

Comment: @DavidPostill - ahhh… it looked like little more than word salad until I'd read it three times. It still shows zero research, so the downvote remains. I can't retract the flag though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find what: `.+(.{10})$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Enable `Wrap around`

Comment: I tried to find and apply a regular expression that cuts the number of characters from the beginning, but it didn't work out, so I asked you a question.
Thank you for your quick response.